# NETLINK_NFLOG support in Linux 4.14

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netfilter

I've this program which runs fine on Linux 2.6.34. While porting this program to 4.14, socket creation is giving error "Error: : Protocol not supported". As per http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html

NETLINK_NFLOG (up to and including Linux 3.16)
Netfilter/iptables ULOG.

Do we know what is the alternative in 4.14 ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_nl addr;
    int mypid;
    int status;
    int sockfd = -1;

    /* mypid = getpid(); */
    mypid = pthread_self();

    sockfd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_NFLOG);
    if (sockfd <= 0) {
        printf("netlink socket() failed - rc:%d, errno:%d\n",
                sockfd, errno);
        perror("Error: ");
        return (-1);
    }

    /* set up socket address */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof (addr));
    addr.nl_pid = mypid;
    addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    /*
       nl_groups is the multicast
       group ID to which the ULOG
       messages will be sent.It
       is bitmap of hexadecimal
       format
       */
    addr.nl_groups = 1;

    /* bind socket to listen on
     * multicast group 1 */
    status = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof (addr));
    if (status < 0) {
        perror("bind:");
        close(sockfd);
        return (-1);
    }

    printf("socket bind successful\n");

    close(sockfd);
    return (0);
}
```

I tried to browse kernel source but couldn't identify.

I've below config

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_INGRESS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_GLUE_CT is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNSECMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_NAT=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NETMAP is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFLOG=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPMSS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_POLICY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE=y
```

Answer (score -1):

NETLINK_NFLOG (up to and including Linux 3.16)
see worked example in libnml